# Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 109, so returning the closest version found: 108

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium and when I run a simple program to login using username and password, I get the error
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 109, so returning the closest version found: 108
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75)
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'

Could you advise please?

To login using selenium code